reactpdf-renderer i want pdf to be rendered when i click on the download button
when the page gets rendered first time, pdf also getting rendered even if i might not use it. So it affect the app badly. some performance issues appears.
When i clicked on the 'Download' button i want pdf to be rendered then gets installed.
{data &&  ( <PDFDownloadLink fileName="FORM" document={<PdfInternform data={data.data} />}> {({ loading }) => loading ? (<DownloadButton variant="outlined" loading={loading} text='Loading...'}></DownloadButton>) :  (<DownloadButton variant="outlined" loading={loading} text={'Download...'}> </DownloadButton>)}</PDFDownloadLink>)}
